# Using .htaccess to block a domain, except for specific pages

Tags: .htaccess

Our website receives visits which originate from our advertisements on www.mywedding.com    For some unknown reason, we are also receiving spurious referrals from other advertisements on that site which have no bearing on our business.  These other visits are skewing our visitor tracking statistics and making it difficult to interpret visitor behavior, because the spurious visitors always leave the site after landing on the home page.  These visits are also distorting our Google Analytics reports.  The webmaster at www.mywedding.com has not been able to determine how this is happening, or how to prevent it.  How can I configure .htaccess to block the spurious visits, while allowing the appropriate visits?  Specifically, I would like to block visits from www.mywedding.com UNLESS the visit originates from either of these three URLs:
www.mywedding.com/vendors/maui-tradewinds-private-honeymoon-retreat-390406 
 or
www.mywedding.com/vendors/maui-tradewinds-private-honeymoon-retreat-276856
 or
www.mywedding.com/honeymoons/united-states/maui-hi-us

Here is the existing code section for blocking specified referrers on my .htaccess:

```
#Block traffic from "bad" referrers
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteBase /
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} make-money-online\.7makemoneyonline\.com [NC,OR]
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} 245\.semalt\.com [NC,OR]
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} best-seo-solution\.com [NC,OR]
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} best-seo-offer\.com [NC,OR]
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} buttons-for-your-website\.com [NC,OR]
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} Get-Free-Traffic-Now\.com [NC,OR]
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} semalt\.com
 RewriteRule .* - [F]
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use these rules:

```
RewriteEngine On

# Inspect visits from www.mywedding.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} (www\.)?mywedding\.com [NC]

# and drop requests NOT from any of three URLs: 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !/vendors/maui-tradewinds-private-honeymoon-retreat-390406 [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !/vendors/maui-tradewinds-private-honeymoon-retreat-276856 [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !/honeymoons/united-states/maui-hi-us [NC]

# Return a 403 Forbidden header which stops the request
RewriteRule .* - [F]
```

The first condition checks that the referrer comes from `www.mywedding.com`. If so, the next conditions make sure that that the referrer is not one of those three URLs you want to whitelist. If all 4 conditions are met (meaning the referrer is from `www.mywedding.com`, but not from a whitelisted URL), then the request is dropped with the final rewrite rule. Otherwise, the URL passes through as it is.

Please experiment with the rules here: http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/

Comment: Thank you for offering that code.  I copied it to the htaccess tester in the link which you provided, and when I press the "check now" button, the page seems to refresh, but there is no response to the test.

Comment: I tested the code on my site, and a request was not dropped, even though it did not originate from any of the "exception" URLs.  Please advise.

Comment: Ah, small typo. Change `RewriteRule .* - [L]` to `RewriteRule .* - [F]`. The "F" means "403 Forbidden" response

Comment: That works totally.  Thank you Drakes -- I had been told by other "experts" that this couldn't be done.

Comment: Glad to be of help. Kindly accept the answer if it benefited you.